# Text tool for designing gameplay elements

Tags: tools, file-format

I'm still in the design phase of my game and I'm realizing that there are too many elements to keep track of and it just looks like a mess in the plain text that I created it in. My notes are basically going to translate to the classes and subclasses that'll make up the objects within my game, but I'd like to find a tool that will make it simpler to keep track of. Here's an example of the structure of my notes:

```
NPCs:
    - Humans:
        - Human A: description
            - Abilities:
                - Ability A: description
                [...]
            - Attributes:
                - Attribute A: description
                [...]
        - Human B: description
            - Abilities:
                - Ability A: description
                [...]
            - Attributes:
                - Attribute A: description
                [...]
    - Elves:
        - Elf A: description
            - Abilities:
                - Ability A: description
                [...]
            - Attributes:
                - Attribute A: description
                [...]
        - Elf B: description
            - Abilities:
                - Ability A: description
                [...]
            - Attributes:
                - Attribute A: description
                [...]
    [...]
World:
    - Continent A: overall description
        - City A: city description
            - Building A: description
            [...]
        [...]
    [...]
Items:
    - Melee: overall description
        - Melee Weapon A: description
            - Damage: X
            - Damage Type: some type
            [...]
        [...]
    - Ranged: overall description
        - Ranged Weapon A: description
            - Damage: X
            - Damage Type: some type
            [...]
        [...]
```

And so on...

Even this simple list is starting to look messy, and once you have pages of classes and multiple subclasses for each class along with lengthy descriptions, it gets really jarring when you view it.

What I would really like is a way to expand and collapse these elements so I can either view the big picture or go down to details, and maybe be able to set some groups a different color or make them bold, etc. for better viewing and categorization. It's basically a class diagram but with more game-world-related descriptions rather than function/method descriptions. I'm currently using Sublime for this, so either a plugin or a different tool that accomplishes this would really help. Thanks!

Comment: Microsoft Excel or it's analogs (e.g. Google Drive Sheets) can do exactly that - collapse-expand cells and groups of cells.

Comment: You may want to ask on the software recommendations SE; we don't consider recommendations on topic here.

Comment: Too broad? I thought I was being as specific as possible as to what I'm trying to achieve. It's not like I was asking "what's the best language to make games in". I have a problem which I detailed and a very clear description of what I'm looking to do. If it's because I should be in Software Recommendations, honestly I don't like how suggestions for every possible subject is in one place. My problem is specific to game design, so I have to go there and hope a game designer will show up there with an answer. You have to understand why this is frustrating.

Comment: Your problem really isn't a game design problem, it's a word processing/text formatting problem, and I say this as a game designer. The topic you want to use this tool for has more in common with software architecture than game design, but even there, your description of a deep & rigid class hierarchy with subclasses for everything actually goes against prevailing advice in game development, which has moved strongly toward composition over inheritance in recent years. If your class structure is too unwieldy to write out simply, imagine trying to develop & debug it!

Comment: @DMGregory I disagree, how to organize and track your information/process is absolutely a design problem.  As with anything else in game design there are a ton of different ways to do things and they are not created equally.  The OP has asked a straight-forward clear question about a game design related issue and it's not at all too broad.

Comment: It's definitely a general programming question, parsing text it would be called. Now if u wanted to parse HLSL and convert that to a c++\c#\vb.net class then I'm sure it would be valid to ask here

Comment: @DMGregory My problem has nothing to do with programming or even class design, I just used that as an example of what I want to do with game-world related concepts. I may not end up using inheritance and subclasses in this way, but I see this as a good way to clearly define my game world and concepts from a 10000ft perspective, down to minute details that I don't want to be lost once I actually get to physically creating the game. I want to clearly define the world, which has continents, which have towns, which have buildings, which have structural details in each building...

Comment: ...Same with NPCs who are a part of these areas that have a backstory, tied to other characters, that have a history, specific skillset, different starting items, etc. If you disregard the part where I say that I plan to translate this into classes (which I didn't even have to mention since it's not part of the problem I'm trying to solve) it is purely a game design problem. I'm trying to efficiently organize a huge amount of game design elements while still maintaining clarity and readability.

Comment: If you were asking about this on the level of design strategies/techniques, I'd refer you to eg. Stone Librande's "One Page Designs" and other designers talking about how they try to break out of the trap of writing massive text documentation. But asking specifically for authoring software puts this question soundly off-topic for this site. As has been noted, we have a dedicated exchange for software recommendations, where this formatting feature request should work just fine. Or you could also try a discussion forum like GameDev.net if you want more back-&-forth than StackExchange Q&A offers.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for pointing me towards that video. I'm very curious about this, especially for games that have massive story structures. I'm always open to better was of going about design!